# Grafana - Configure Custom Metrics from Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, grafana

I am new to Grafana. I am setting it up to view data from Cloudwatch for a Custom Metrics. Custom Metrics Namespace Name is JVMStats, Metric is JVMHeapUsed, Dimension is instance Id. If I configure these data, I am not able to get the graph. Can you please advice me on how to get the data?

Regards
Karthik

Answer (score 3):

I want to do the same.

As far as I can tell, it's not possible out of the box with the latest Grafana (2.6 at time of writing).  See [this issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/3475).

[This](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/3736) pull request implements it.  It's currently tagged as 3.0-beta1.  So I expect we'll both be able to do what we want come version 3.0.

**EDIT: inserting proof of 3.0-beta-1 working**

I installed 3.0-beta-1, and was able to use Custom Metrics, as evidenced by this image:

[image: **grafana datasource for with custom metrics**]

Comment: Hi, I installed 3.0 and still I cannot render the data in graph. I am not sure is it a problem in Graphana or data in cloudwatch. I could render graph in CloudWatch. Datasource connects successfully to ClowdWatch Namespace. When I configure a graph with Namespace, Metrics and Dimension - I am not able to view data. I am leaving the Period and Alias as default. Any recommendations?

Comment: @KarthikPalanivelu I tested 3.0-beta-1, and it works for me.  I edited answer above accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to configure AWS CloudWatch job to collect data into [Axibase Time Series Database](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/) where [CustomMetrics](https://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/writing-data/aws-integration/) namespace is enabled out-of-the-box:

Disclosure: I work for Axibase.

Comment: Hello, it is very informative. Can you let me know if this is Open Source or Licensed, I could not find in your site. Secondly can Axibase able to connect to Cloudwatch using default Profile Id of that EC2?

Comment: I would not plug a paid solution on this forum. ATSD CE is free although it's not open source. There are limitations - such as a limit of 5 active cloudwatch jobs per installation. I recommend connecting through a read-only IAM credentials although fetching Cloudwatch stats through elevated credentials should work as well.

Comment: Edit: the limits have been removed. you can create unlimited number of cloudwatch jobs as well as other jobs: jmx, jdbc, http, file, json, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to add my custom metrics now, only issue I had was that I listed my custom metrics in the "Data Source" configurations with commmas and spaces:

```
Custom1, Custom2
```

but it must be only commas:

```
Custom1,Custom2
```

And it works for me. The preview in the text box shows this, but I missed it.